# Equivalent of stroke-dasharray for svg fill

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there an equivalent attribute to [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) that can be used to manipulate the fill pattern of an SVG? I'm trying to get a hand-writing effect, so the contents should progressively fill in as if the letters are being written in. `stroke-dasharray` doesn't work because it animates the outline of the letters rather than the fill. I created [this codepen](https://codepen.io/OzCodes/pen/QWrvWzZ) where the SVG paths have `fill: transparent` to illustrate this. If there's no equivalent attribute that controls how the fill is applied, can you suggest an alternative way for me to achieve my desired effect?

Comment: you could use a gradient and manipulate the stops.

Comment: Take a look at [my article on animated calligraphy](https://browser-unplugged.net/blog/calligraphy.en.html).

Comment: @ccprog, you can strike the _does not work Edge_ text; works great in every modern browser, thank you for the great work.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman you're right, that is now outdated. Edge before v79, released in 2020, did not support SMIL animations, but I think that could now be considered a problem of the past.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content=
         "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <style>
         .path {
         stroke-dasharray: 3000;
         stroke-dashoffset: 3000;
         animation: dash 5s linear forwards infinite;
         }
         @keyframes dash {
         to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 0;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 640 640">
         <path class="path" fill="white"
            stroke="black" stroke-width="4"
            d="M70.74 411.89L91.42 411.89L112.09 411.89L114.39
            391.22L114.39 370.54L110.95 349.86L114.39 329.19L115.54
            308.51L115.54 287.84L125.88 270.61L146.55 269.46L167.23
            269.46L176.42 287.84L172.97 308.51L172.97 329.19L172.97
            351.01L172.97 371.69L174.12 392.36L184.46 409.59L205.14
            409.59L225.81 410.74L230.41 390.07L229.26 369.39L226.96
            348.72L226.96 328.04L231.55 307.36L235 286.69L228.11
            267.16L247.64 259.12L268.31 259.12L288.99 261.42L303.92
            275.2L299.32 297.03L297.03 317.7L297.03 339.53L298.18
            360.2L298.18 380.88L299.32 401.55L318.85 406.15L339.53
            406.15L349.86 388.92L352.16 368.24L355.61 347.57L355.61
            326.89L354.46 305.07L352.16 284.39L351.01 263.72L370.54
            256.82L391.22 256.82L411.89 260.27L411.89 280.95L411.89
            302.77L413.04 323.45L416.49 345.27L418.78 365.95L421.08
            386.62L436.01 401.55L456.69 402.7L477.36 403.85L481.96
            384.32L484.26 363.65L484.26 342.97L484.26 320L479.66
            300.47L473.92 279.8L469.32 260.27L465.88 239.59L465.88
            218.92L448.65 208.58L427.97 208.58L406.15 208.58L384.32
            208.58L362.5 208.58L341.82 208.58L321.15 208.58L299.32
            207.43L277.5 205.14L255.68 205.14L232.7 202.84L212.03
            201.69L190.2 201.69L168.38 202.84L144.26 206.28L122.43
            208.58L101.76 210.88L81.08 210.88L60.41 210.88L53.51
            231.55L50.07 252.23L47.77 274.05L47.77 295.88L46.62
            317.7L45.47 338.38L45.47 360.2L48.92 380.88L54.66
            400.41L69.59 414.19" />
      </svg>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this  animation

Comment: I appreciate the effort but this simply recycles the strategy that isn't working without offering any solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).